# A File object in Chrome passed between windows is no longer an instanceof File

Tags: google-chrome

Updated after answer - Based on the answer below, I decided to make a copy of the file in the destination page so that it would be an instanceof that window's File object.

```
function makeFileLocal(file, callBack) {
    var localFile;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("loadend", function () {
        // reader.result contains the contents of blob as a typed array
        var a = new Array(reader.result);
        localFile = new File(a, file.name, { type: file.type, lastModified: file.lastModified });
        callBack(localFile);
    });
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

I placed this function in the destination page, and called it from the file originator by `window.opener.makeFileLocal(file, callback)`. Now I had a file to pass back to the destination window that matched its File object.

=================== Original question ======================

I'm passing a File object between two Chrome windows in a function. In the target window I need the object to evaluate to an instance of `File`, but it doesn't.

In the Chrome console, in the passing browser, `object instanceof File` evaluates to true; when the object is passed to the target window, `object instanceof File` evaluates to false. But in the target window `Object.prototype.toString.call(file) === '[object File]'` evaluates to true. All attributes of the file object remain the same.

To recreate the issue use the two pages below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function displayFiles(files) {
            window.alert("File 0 is a file? " + (files[0] instanceof File)); // false, should be true
            window.alert("It's an object that's a file though, right? " + (Object.prototype.toString.call(files[0]) === '[object File]')); // true
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Page 1</h1>

    <div onclick="window.open('page2.html');">
        Click here to open page two...
    </div>
    <div id="files">
        Files:
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the second page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sendFiles() {
            var files = document.getElementById('files').files
            window.alert("File 0 is a file? " + (files[0] instanceof File)); // true
            window.opener.displayFiles(files);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Page 2</h1>

    <div onclick="sendFiles();">
        Click here to send files...
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="file" id="files" multiple="multiple" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

These pages have to be served, Chrome complains about the cross window scripting if just launched from the files. Any ideas would be much appreciated, and if there's anything I can clarify let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking against the wrong `File` class.

Since each window has its own scope, you need

```
files[0] instanceof opener.File
```

Comment: Thank you, that was what was happening. Something I will keep in mind from now on!